# Cannot convert method group to non-delegate type

Tags: asp.net

```
var deletedItems = tmpData.FindAll(qr => (Int32)qr.YearQuarter < (Int32)useDate.YearQuarter);'
```

`userdate.yearquarter` is

```
<Extension()>
  Public Function YearQuarter(currentDate As Date) As Integer
    Return Library.Dates.ToYearQuarter(currentDate)
  End Function
```

I am getting an error here:

```
"< (Int32)useDate.YearQuarter;"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling `YearQuarter` correctly; you need to do `YearQuarter(DateObject)`. Without the parens, you are trying to pass the `method group` that represents the function - not the return value of the function.